# I always get this message alone when I try to execute in main method "ArrayStack@6acbcfc0"

Tags: java, methods, error-handling, stack, program-entry-point

I have to create a method on stacks. For some reason when I try to execute from the main method it ALWAYS shows something like `ArrayStack@6acbcfc0` even thought I take the answer from the answers sheet. What is wrong? This is my coding for the method and the main class.

Stack method:

```
public static void splitStack(ArrayStack<Integer> st1,ArrayStack<Integer> st2)
    {
        ArrayStack<Integer> st11 = new ArrayStack<Integer>();
        ArrayStack<Integer> st2rev = new ArrayStack<Integer>();
        while(!st1.isEmpty())
        {
            st11.push(st1.pop());
            if(!st1.isEmpty())
                st2rev.push(st1.pop());
        }
        while(!st11.isEmpty())
            st1.push(st11.pop());
        while(!st2rev.isEmpty())
            st2.push(st2rev.pop());

    }
```

main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
      
        ArrayStack<Integer> s1 = new ArrayStack<>();
        ArrayStack<Integer> s2 = new ArrayStack<>();
        s1.push(0);
        s1.push(1);
        s1.push(3);
        s1.push(4);
        s1.splitStack(s1,s2);
        System.out.println(s2);
    }
```

output:

```
ArrayStack@6acbcfc0

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: You should override the `toString()` method of your `ArrayStack` class if you want a more meaningful output.

Comment: okay thanks, but how am i gonna do that ? what is the body of the ` toString() `  going to be?

Comment: *"what is the body of the ` toString() ` going to be?"* - Whatever you want!  Its purpose is to render an instance of your class into a form that users can read.  You can include as little or as much information in the result string as you want or need to.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass an object to `System.out.println()`, it tries to figure out what to do with it, i.e., which object type it is to pass to the method. If it can't figure anything else, it uses the object's `toString()` method (so it can pass a string to `println()`), and the output you've shown looks like the default output of `toString()` for an arbitrary object. If you override `toString()` in your class, then when `println()` invokes it it will execute your code instead of the default code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use s2.toString() in System.out.println() statement which is in main method.

like - System.out.println(s2.toString());

Comment: still shows as ```ArrayStack@6acbcfc0

Process finished with exit code 0 ``` .. bcz i dohnt know what to put in the body of toString()

Comment: try to change return type of splitStack() method list instead of void and do same as I told before.